# If there are multiple workers assigned to a dataflow pipeline, will they be able to access global variables?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Basically I am running a pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow using the apache beam python SDK.
First, I am reading a JSON string from cloud pubsub and checking against a global dictionary variable whether data has already been received with the ID. If it is the first message with the ID, then I add the ID as a key to my dictionary and the message received as the value, otherwise I don't change the dictionary. Basically I am adding a key to the dictionary every time a new one is received.
Next, I monitor for changes in the data by comparing the newly received data with the last reading.

Will using a common variable cause any problems once the number of workers handling the dataflow job become more than 1?

The way I have currently written the pipeline works, but right now only one worker is handling the gcp dataflow job. I am not sure if any problems will arise if another worker is assigned.

Here I have added a simplified version of the code, but the actual code has multiple branches checking for different sorts of events.

```py
dictionary={}
class AddId2Dict(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,e):
        if(e[0] not in dictionary.keys()):
            dictionary[e[0]]=e[1]
        return((e,))
class ChangeChecker(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,e):
       if(e[0] in dictionary.keys()):
            if dictionary[e[0]]<e[1]:
                print 'Increase occurred for id:'+str(e[0])|
                dictionary[e[0]]=e[1]
            elif dictionary[e[0]]>e[1]:
                print 'Decrease occurred for id:'+str(e[0])
            else:
                print 'Stayed constant for id:'+str(e[0])

def run():
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
    (
     p
     | 'read from pubsub'<<beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic_name).with_output_type(bytes)
     | 'parse json & create tuple' >> beam.Map(lambda e: ((json.loads(x)['id'],int(json.loads(x)['data'])))
     | 'add key to dict if it does not exist' >> beam.ParDo(AddId2Dict())
     | 'check for event' >> beam.ParDo(ChangeChecker())
    )
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__  ==  '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Each worker will create its own copy of the `dictionary` variable.

If you want workers to share a global state, you can use the Beam State API. In python it is the `userstate` module (https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.13.0/apache_beam.transforms.userstate.html).